ReactJS - Serve : SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
First time trying to run reactJS project in production. I might have just missed something stupid.
On my server, npm start works perfectly. Now I want to run it in production mode, so I did:
npm install -g serve
npm run build # correctly creates /build folder
serve -s build

Now I am getting:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/build/main.js:4
import { cwd as getPwd, exit, env as env2, stdout } from "node:process";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

What did I miss?
What I have already tried:

My nodeJS server runs on port 3001, so I also tried to run serve -s build -l 3001, but it results in the same error message

Somebody said to not install serve globally and instead run npm -S serve - doesnt work

npx serve {...} also does not work (prints just Unexpected token {)



You are using a very old version of Node, which doesn't support the features required by serve.
The current version of serve (14) states the following in its documentation:

serve v14 onwards requires Node v14 to run. Please use serve v13 if you cannot upgrade to Node v14.

You need to upgrade to a newer version of Node, preferably the current Long-Term Support version, which is Node 20 at the time of writing.
If it is not an option, you could try running an earlier version of serve, e.g. version 13:
npx serve@13 -s build

